# How To Determine How Much Data Left In The Log

Tags: mysql, replication, monitoring

I have 2 servers set up using MySQL. It's using a standard replication setup, with one slave, no circular replication.

Is there a way to programmatically tell how far behind the slave is in reading the data from the binary log?

If I run the statement:

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

On the master, and run

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
```

on the slave, I can compare the Position column from master status, and the Read_Master_Log_Pos column from slave status to determine how far behind the slave is.

However, this only works if the slave is reading from the same file the master is writing to.  So if the slave is still reading a previous log file, because it is running behind, I can't figure out how to determine how much data is left until it catches up to the current position that the master is at.  A solution using only SQL would be optimal, but I'm open to other solutions.  Hopefully not one that requires reading the directory containing the log files.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the 'Seconds_behind_master' field from SHOW SLAVE STATUS in order to determine if the MASTER-SLAVE servers are caught up.  As a secondary guard I also to a COUNT(*) query on a specific table (ie one that gets updated frequently) on both servers and then compare the record counts.